# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1000050TPAR' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting this error when running this specific SQL query.

It used to work before. Not sure if certain values from the ID e.g. 1000050TPAR is causing this to fail.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable 
(
     [ID] INT,
     [CarID] VARCHAR (8), 
     [Dates] DATE 
) 
GO

INSERT INTO #TempTable ([ID], [CarID], [Dates])
    SELECT 
        ordnum AS [ID], 
        wh_id AS [CarID], 
        DATEADD(DAY, -10, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS [Dates] 
    FROM
        ord 
    WHERE
        customer_id = '150' 
        AND moddte BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -10, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()

SELECT * FROM #TempTable

DROP TABLE #TempTable
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible integer conversion in this code is `ordnum` when loaded into the temporary table, because the corresponding column is for integers.  You can find the offending values by using:

```
select ordnum
from ord
where try_convert(int, ordnum) is null;
```

The likely solution, though, is to use the same type in the temporary table as in the raw data.  Or even to change the code to:

```
select ordnum as [ID], 
       wh_id as [CarID], 
       dateadd(day, -10, cast(getdate() as date)) as [Dates] 
into #TempTable
from ord
where customer_id = '150' and 
      moddte between dateadd(day, -10, getdate()) and getdate();
```

Then you don't need to declare the types of the columns at all.

The `where` clause can probably be simplified to `moddte >= dateadd(day, -10, getdate())` because modification dates are unlikely to be in the future.